# Sometimes Wifi Hotspot is not turning on with android 5.1 device

Tags: android, hotspot

We are trying to switch ON wifi hotspot programatically but sometimes it goes in an infinite loop and does not switch ON but mostly it works. This is the line where it hangs "while (!(Boolean) isWifiApEnabledMethod.invoke(wifiManager)) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            };"
Entire code is placed below. This is only a problem with Android 5.0/5.1 devices. Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService   (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    //If Wifi is ON then switch it OFF
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }

    WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    Random random = new Random();
    int iRandomKey = random.nextInt(65536);

    netConfig.SSID = "TestHotspot";
    netConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    netConfig.priority = 40;
    //hiding SSID,
    netConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
    netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    netConfig.preSharedKey = "testpassword";

    final String RingOfFire_Ssid = netConfig.SSID;
    final String RingOfFire_password = netConfig.preSharedKey;

    try {
        Method setWifiApMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled",   WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        boolean apstatus = (Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig, true);
        Log.d("ConnectWIFI:", "apstatus" + ":" + apstatus);

        Method isWifiApEnabledMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
        while (!(Boolean) isWifiApEnabledMethod.invoke(wifiManager)) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        };

        Method getWifiApConfigurationMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        netConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getWifiApConfigurationMethod.invoke(wifiManager);

        Log.d("ConnectWIFI:", netConfig.SSID + ":" + netConfig.preSharedKey + ":" + "Hotspot");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e);
    }
```

We explored further and we get better behavior when we use this method

```
    Class<?> cls=WifiManager.class; 
   for (Method method:cls.getDeclaredMethods()){ 
   String methodName=method.getName(); 
   if (methodName.equals("getWifiApState")){ getWifiApState=method; }
   else if (methodName.equals("isWifiApEnabled")){ isWifiApEnabled=method; }
   else if (methodName.equals("setWifiApEnabled")){ setWifiApEnabled=method; }
   else if (methodName.equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {       getWifiApConfiguration=method; } }
```

Thanks

Comment: `Log.d("ConnectWIFI:", "apstatus" + ":" + apstatus);`. Have you seen differences in `appstatus` when this happens?

Comment: No , I am not sure what you mean.


We explored further and we get better behavior when we use this method

    Class<?> cls=WifiManager.class;
  for (Method method:cls.getDeclaredMethods()){
   String methodName=method.getName();
   if (methodName.equals("getWifiApState")){
    getWifiApState=method;
   }else if (methodName.equals("isWifiApEnabled")){
    isWifiApEnabled=method;
   }else if (methodName.equals("setWifiApEnabled")){
    setWifiApEnabled=method;
   }else if (methodName.equals("getWifiApConfiguration"))    {
    getWifiApConfiguration=method;
   }
  }

Comment: As mentioned in https://github.com/ProjectSPAN/android-manet-manager/blob/master/AndroidManetManager/src/org/servalproject/system/WifiApControl.java


But still sometimes it does not work

Comment: I cannot read code in comments! Can you? Please put it in an extra code block in your post.

Comment: `I am not sure what you mean`. Well what is normally logged? And what is logged if it hangs? Does it differ?